# Octave : using bar and histc

Tags: histogram, octave

I want to plot unequal width histograms.

x = [10 12 15 18]   #bin edges
y = [3 2 6]         #corresponding frequences
bar(e, c, 'histc')

I get the following output:

warning: implicit conversion from matrix to string
error: set: unknown property "

"
error: called from:
error:   /usr/share/octave/3.2.3/m/plot/**bars**.m at line 120, column 7
error:   /usr/share/octave/3.2.3/m/plot/**bar**.m at line 161, column 7
error:   /usr/share/octave/3.2.3/m/plot/bar.m at line 67, column 19

It seems that histc isn't working.
I have octave 3.2 installed.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
help bar
```

to get information about the parameters. You will see that `'histc'` is not a valid style option (this is only supported in Matlab).

If you need to count the frequencies of your data the [histc](http://octave.sourceforge.net/octave/function/histc.html) function can do this.

Comment: It actually is a supported [style option](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/v4.0.0/Two_002dDimensional-Plots.html) now as far as I'm typing this comment.